# calling a function from a project without import that project

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have some major issue here. This will be a little bit complex situation. I have 3 java project namely A, B and C. Projects A and C have B as the .jar file, means that, B act as a library for these A and C projects. What I want to do is, I want to get a function from any java file in A project and use it in java file in C project without import the java file to C. And the only way to connect between these two project is via project B. can some one help me solve this? let me give an example:

there is aa.java in project A, and the function in it is:

```
private static boolean keyBlocking = false;
public static boolean iskeyBlocking() {
    return keyBlocking;
}
```

i want to use this function in cc.java in the C project without import this aa.java to C project. I hope this example helps to understand my question.

Comment: This is not possible. Either link project A to project C or add A's jar(s) to C. BTW A has B . So b doesn't have access to A's APIs. It means A can use B's APIs

Comment: both A and C have B's API. can we create 1 java file in B that link A and C? my idea is use this: `public class bb extends aa {`. can we do something like this?

Comment: Well, making `bb` extend `aa` would mean that project B has the jar for project A.

Comment: @squallleonhart - No. That would lead to cyclic dependency. b has a and a has b. Your project will not build

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use a class from another project without linking the project as dependent project/jar.

It is not possible.
In your scenario, you have common project(helper/utility) which is linked to both the projects A and C.

May be you can move the current class 'aa.java' to the project B.

**"I want to get a function from any java file in A project and use it in java file in C project without import the java file to C" **

Taking the statement literally "without import the java file to C", you can directly use it without import as below.

If the package is 'com.app.test', class is AA.java.

**Using import:**

import com.app.test.AA

public void someMethod()

{

```
 AA.iskeyBlocking();
```

}

**Without using import:**

*// NO IMPORT*

public void someMethod()

{

```
  com.app.test.AA.iskeyBlocking();
```

}